# Proving that any set X that has an upper bound and is non-empty, has a least upper bound

Tags: calculus, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

so this is the problem I am having trouble with:

> Let X ⊆ R be a set of real numbers that is non-empty and bounded from
>   above. Then X has a least upper bound.

So, my approach was the following:

> We know that X has an upper bound and let $y$ be the upper bound of
>   $X$. If $y$ is the upper bound of $X$, then $y \geq x$ (for all $x \in
>  X$).

So by contrapositive, this means:

> If $y < x$, then $y$ is not an upper bound. Thus, $y$ is the least
>   upper bound.

I would appreciate your help and any advice about my approach. Just to clarify, this is not part of any assignment, it is just an exercise I am doing to practice.

Comment: How is $\Bbb R$ defined to you? Can you use that bounded, increasing sequences converge? There are probably many other questions I can ask that will help, but let's start with those two.

Comment: Your argument seems to imply all upper bounds are least upper bounds.